# How to copy table from Production to Development?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working on Development Server Named as `SQLDEV01` and the db name is `University` and the table name is `cse.students`. During my work on table cse.students I lost some rows so I need to get the all the exact data from Production server.production Server Name is `SQLPROD01`.

How can I query to get the production data without using SSIS?

Comment: How many rows do you have in this table in production?

Comment: Add it as a linked server? Then you can query directly  (insert cse.students select * from SQLPROD01.University.cse.students)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx#SSMSProcedure

Comment: @peter.petrov.Nearly 2k rows

Comment: Do you have a linked server setup (or want one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. One that is pretty much failsafe is the following:

In Microsoft SQL Management Studio expand the server node for the source server - Then expand the Databases node. Right click on the source database and select Tasks -> Generate Scripts. When the dialog pops up click next. Select the "Select specific database objects" radio button. Expand the Tables node as check the table you want to copy. Click the next button at the bottom. Click the advanced button. In the options that pop up for Script DROP and CREATE select Script DROP and CREATE on the right. For the option Type of data to script select schema and data on the right. Click OK. Now back on the main dialog you need to select "Save to Clipboard" or "Save to new query window". I usually select clipboard because I am usually going to a different server but select what works best for you. Click next. Click next again and the script will generate according to your selections. Now just run that script on the destination database.

[image]

Comment: The script just dropping the table and creating new table.

Comment: Did you select "schema and data" for the Type of data to script option?

Comment: I updated my answer with a screenshot for selecting that option correctly.

Comment: i used clip board but where can i get query to run on my Development DB.

Comment: If you used the clipbord you just past it into the query page in SQL Management Studio on the destination DB and then run it. Think of using the clipboard as the cut part of a cut and past operation

Answer (score 4):

Setup a linked server from the development to production servers before doing the following from SSMS.  All code should be executed on the development server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

```
-- On Development server [SQLDEV01]
TRUNCATE TABLE [University].[cse].[students];
GO

-- Use link server to move data
INSERT INTO 
    [University].[cse].[students] 
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    [SQLPROD01].[University].[cse].[students] 
GO
```

This assumes there are no identity columns on the target.

If you do have identity columns, turn on/off allow inserts before/after executing the above insert.

```
-- Before Insert, execute this statement
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [University].[cse].[students] ON
GO


-- After Insert, execute this statement
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [University].[cse].[students] OFF
GO
```

You can also create an ad-hoc connection using the OPENROWSET command.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

```
INSERT INTO 
    [University].[cse].[students] 
SELECT 
    PRD.*
FROM 
    OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=SQLPROD01;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
    'SELECT * FROM [University].[cse].[students]') AS PRD;
```

I did not check the syntax for your environment, please check.

If add hoc queries are set off (0), have the DBA turn them on (1) temporarily.  Execute the following on the production server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187569.aspx

```
-- Show all settings
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO

-- What is the current setting?
sp_configure 
GO

-- Allow add hoc queries    
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

If (s)he does not allow that, you are stuck with a physical linked server.

If you are using **delegation** - choice #3, you have to watch out for the double hop issue.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/08/10/694657.aspx

I would configure the linked server with a specific account on production that has rights to select the data.  See choice #4.

[image]

Comment: :Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', search for 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' in SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: If you can not browse from SSMS -> Linked Server -> tables, you do not have it setup correctly.  Please write back if you still have issues.

Answer (score 1):

please use this query generalized query by replacing your entries

select * into targetTable from [sourceserver].[sourcedatabase].[dbo].[sourceTable]

Comment: :Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Comment: For the linked server, the correct credentials need to be set up.  It is defaulting to Anonymous.